# Show @class field in SQL result set

Tags: orientdb

When using OrientDB console, i want to show the @class field in the SQL result set (especially when working with the traverse command). How do i do this? Could not find anything in the documentation. When using the Java API this is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was fixed **9** days ago and is now in the **latest release** https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb/issues/2881

Answer (score 1):

i've tried with 1.7.x and yes is is not printed @class
With 2.x it is there

Which version of OrientDB do you have?

If you want to display @class you can also do something like this

select *, @class as class from V